# The current path, accounts/<int:id>/, didn’t match any of these ( for django application)

Tags: python, django

This is a book exchange system I'm trying to create. The challlenge I'm having is trying to redirect the user to a dynamic url consisting of there personal details after log in.

Here is my urs.py for my project

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include


urlpatterns = [
    path('exchange/',include('exchange.urls')),
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Here is my urs.py for my app

```
from django.urls import path
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from . import views



urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.base, name='base'),
    path('register/', views.register_request, name='register'),
    path('accounts/<int:id>/', views.user_view, name='userview'),
    #path('login/', views.login_request, name='login'),
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='exchange/login.html', redirect_field_name='user_view')),

]
```

Here is my views.py for my app

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from exchange.forms import user_login_form, user_register_form
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib import messages

# Create your views here.


#Base index view
def base(request):
    return render(request, 'exchange/base.html',{})

#registration view
def register_request(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        form = user_register_form(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            user = User.objects.create_user(username=username, email=email, password=password)
            user.save()
            return redirect('login')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Invalid form')
            render(request, 'exchange/register.html',{'form':form})
            
    else:
        form = user_register_form()
        return render(request, 'exchange/register.html',{'form':form})

#login view
def login_request(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        form = user_login_form(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('user_view', id=user.id)
            else:
                messages.error(request, 'Invalid username or password')
                render(request, 'exchange/login.html',{'form':form})
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Invalid form')
            render(request, 'exchange/login.html',{'form':form})
    form = user_login_form()
    return render(request, 'exchange/login.html',{'form':form})


#userview
def user_view(request, id):
    user = User.objects.get(id=id)
    return render(request, 'exchange/user_view.html',{'user':user})
```

I have also added LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/accounts/int:id/' to my settings.py.

Answer (score 0):

I presume your app is called `exchange`

because you've put this `'accounts/<int:id>'` inside your exchange app's urls, it's actually trying to match for `'exchange/accounts/<int:id>'`

```py
path('exchange/',include('exchange.urls')),
# Link App's Urls -> 'exchange/{x}'.format(pattern)

# exchange.urls (prepend 'exchange')
  # url: exchange
  path('', views.base, name='base'),

  # url: exchange/register
  path('register/', views.register_request, name='register'),

  # url: exchange/accounts/<int:id>
  path('accounts/<int:id>/', views.user_view, name='userview'),

  # etc
```

There's really no way around this prepending, so i think your best bet would be to put it in the main urls and just explicitly say what app + view

```
from django.urls import path
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from . import views
from exchange.views import user_view

urlpatterns = [
    path('exchange/',include('exchange.urls')),
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('accounts/<int:id>', user_view, name='userview'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not see your models but are you sure that you use user_id like

```
<int:id>
```

Normally I use pk like this

```
<int:pk>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the following name in your URLs.py

```
path('accounts/<int:id>/', views.user_view, ***name='userview'***),
```

But you are using a different name (with an underscore) in your redirect

```
return redirect(***'user_view'***, id=user.id)
```

They will need to match for the redirect to work

Answer (score 0):

int:id/, didn’t match any of these - An incorrect letter or symbol in the route is invisible to the eye, so rewrite the route completely manually. in my case, perhaps I wrote the letter "A" in another language